# Filtering objects through a range of object attribute in Django-rest-framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I am making a Rest API in Django Rest Framework for which I have a model which stores data like this-

```
   class Commodity(models.Model):
      def countryname(self):
        return self.country.country_name
      country=models.ForeignKey(Country)
      commodity_name=models.CharField(max_length=255)
      commodity_type=models.IntegerField(choices=COMMODITY_TYPE)
      commodity_year=models.IntegerField(default=None)
      commodity_production=models.IntegerField(default=None)

      def __unicode__(self):
        return self.commodity_name +"-"+str(self.country.country_name)
```

Now I want to get all those objects which fall in a range of commodity_year, for example, all those object whose `commodity_year` is between 1999 to 2014 (both inclusive). I have been using `Django-filter` class for this but got no luck.

```
class CommodityFilter(filters.FilterSet):
   start_date = DateFilter(name='commodity_year' )
   end_date = DateFilter(name='commodity_year')
   class Meta:
    model = Commodity
    fields =  [ 'country','commodity_name', 'commodity_type','start_date','end_date']


 class CommodityList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):

   queryset = Commodity.objects.all()
   serializer_class = CommoditySerializer
   filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
   filter_class = CommodityFilter
   permission_classes = [AllowAny]
```

If anyone has a better approach please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in `CommodityFilter` class:

```
class CommodityFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    start_date = django_filters.NumberFilter(
        name='commodity_year', lookup_expr='gte')
    end_date = django_filters.NumberFilter(
        name='commodity_year', lookup_expr='lte')

    class Meta:
        model = Commodity
        fields =  [ 'country','commodity_name', 'commodity_type','start_date','end_date']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can filter with a range using less than equal to and greater than equal  to.

```
queryset = Commodity.objects.filter(commodity_year__gte=1999,
                                    commodity_year__lte=2014)
```

The above will give you a queryset where `commodity_year` is less than 2014 and greater than 1999. Read more about [gt](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#gt) at django docs

Note: I don't think filter class is needed as it is a very simple query